# How can Hermione cast a spell without using her wand in this scene?

Tags: harry-potter

During Quidditch trials in the movie version of *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, Hermione casts Confundus to sabotage Cormac McLaggen and allow Ron to become keeper. She appears to do so without her wand, as shown  [here](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Confundus_Charm#Known_uses). How did she manage to cast the spell without a wand?

Comment: Links have a habit of becoming obsolete, could you add the relevant quote and reference to the body of the question to ensure future visitors can understand what you're asking.

Comment: Same in the video game. Wandless - https://youtu.be/rKOG2zkkU7o?t=890

Comment: How do you suppose Harry made the glass disappear at the reptile house when the Dursleys went to the zoo in the first book/movie? He didn't have a wand there.

Comment: Of course, I always assumed Hermione was just holding her wand surreptitiously in her left hand, since it is out of frame.

Comment: @TylerH - I thought that, but in the previous frame her hands are in her lap and her non-face-covering arm doesn't appear to have moved at all.

Comment: @Valorum Hmm, fair point; I didn't remember all the details from before/after the clip shown in the link. Either way your answer is the best response, both for this and for any other question about wandless magic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

She didn't cast it *wordlessly*, she evidently muttered the curse.

> Hermione, face buried in her fingers, MUTTERS SOMETHING.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - Screenplay](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:butrNfqCRKsJ:www.cinefile.biz/script/potter6.pdf%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)</sup></sub>

She did however cast it *wandlessly*, which is described by JKR as being a sophisticated form of magic that requires talent, something that Hermione has in abundance.

> [JKR:](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/707220859388305408/) Yes, nearly all wizards use wands, which makes magic easier to channel. Wandless magic is sophisticated and takes more talent.

Comment: I believe that Professor Dumbledore lit the floating candles at Hogwarts without using a wand.

Comment: @user57467 - There are umpteen instances of [wandless magic](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wandless_magic) in the films and books. This is simply one of them

Answer (score 2):

The wand just focuses your magic power, doesn't create it. It is like some kind of magic booster.

Imagine a lens that you can use to concentrate sunlight to burn something. If there is no sunlight it will not work (like a wand in the hand of muggle). If you don't have a lens you can't concentrate the sunlight but sunlight does not disappear.  Perhaps not the best analogy, but it roughly shows how the magic wand works.

The [Harry Potter's wiki](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wandless_magic) tells:

"Wands were used by witches and wizards to channel their magic, making their spells more accurate and potent."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What's a "magic buster?"  Can you provide a reference for this?  An example of someone performing a standard spell without a wand?

Comment: @DavidW Imagine the lense that you can use to concentrate the sunlight to burn something. If there is no sunlight it will not work (like a wand in the hand of muggle). If you don't have a lense you can't concentrate the sunlight but sunlight is not dissapear. If you have a huge mass, you can concentrate the sunlight by curving the spacetime.

Perhaps not the best analogy, but it roughly shows how the magic wand works.

Comment: A relevant quote from the books backing up your statement would improve this answer greatly

Comment: @fez I don't know the Harry Potter universe so much, it is just a my assumption. But I remember a lot of scenes in books where characters used magic without wand. And even without spelling any words.

Comment: I think "focuses" would be more accurate than "increases". Otherwise squibs and perhaps even muggles would be able to do magic just by holding a wand.